How can I prohibit access to certain generated .NET8 Identity endpoints?
I have created an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC web application and scaffolded Identity on to it, only accepting a few pages (Login, Registration, Forgot Password, etc).
What I've discovered with some research is that the endpoints are automatically created and I can't change that. What I want to do is to not allow access to those endpoints I'm not using.
For example, let's say I wanted to not allow /Register to be reached and subsequent generated form page not shown. How do I go about doing that?
I was hoping I could have something in program.cs that I could list those I wanted to prevent access and have them return a 403 error.

You could (1) try to use a reverse proxy such as Yarp to control access to such endpoints, or (2) at least for .NET 8, decide not to use the generated endpoints and instead implement your own.

We don't have options in Program.cs to set restrictions for identity pages, and just like you know, event if we don't scaffold all pages of identity, we could still visit them. What we can do is scaffolding those pages to add Authorization roles if we want to have 403 error, and we could manage the account/index page to delete other pages' enterences to make them not available on page. Anyway, your requirement is very special while the default identity is designed for general, so that maybe need to implement yourself for your custom requirement.

I provided an answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78818645/1758319

@DavidPoxon, I may give your answer a try.  What I did was to scaffold all of the possible pages, and simply require authorization which forces the user to the login page.  But if your solution works, it would result in cleaner code.  Thank you for the comment.
